# Perl Mason Syntax Validation

Tags: perl, syntax, validation, mason

Is there a way to validate perl mason syntax at the command line?  I know for regular perl modules you can just use `perl -c`, but that throws errors for mason-specific syntax like docstrings and the like...

For example:

```
<%doc>
DOCUMENTATION SHOULD NOT GET PARSED
</%doc>

<%args>
$args
</%args>

<%perl>
my $var = $args->{var};
</%perl>
```

is a valid perl mason file, but running `perl -c` against it returns:

```
Semicolon seems to be missing at path/to/file.mc line 1.
syntax error at path/to/file.mc line 2, near "DOCUMENTATION S"
path/to/file.mc had compilation errors.
```

Comment: For a module, you should use `perl -e'use Module;'`. `perl -c Module.pm` can cause problems.

Comment: You may be correct on that.  I am new to perl, and have never needed this sort of command before.  That being said, it definitely doesn't work for mason *.mc files, which is what I need.

Comment: Didn't mean to imply it does. Mason is not Perl, so `perl` can't execute it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I took a look at Mason, the first thing I see is  [Mason::App](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mason::App)/[mason.pl](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Mason/bin/mason.pl)

```
$ mason junk.mason
Invalid attribute line '$args' at ./junk.mason line 6
```

Neat huh? But that actually tries to  *run* the code, so next step is look inside, and after a little looking around, i find [Mason::Interp](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mason::Interp) which has [load (path)](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mason::Interp#load-path) which is documented as

> Returns the component object corresponding to an absolute component
>   path, or undef if none exists. Dies with an error if the component
>   fails to load because of a syntax error.

So you can adapt Mason::App to load instead of run or make your own simple version like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
use strict; use warnings; use Mason;
my $interp = Mason->new(
    comp_root => '/path/to/comps',
    data_dir  => '/path/to/data',
    ...
);
$interp->load( shift );
```

Comment: Excellent, detailed answer!  Adding a bounty (not awardable for 24 hours) for high quality.

Comment: Upvoting for voluntarily offering a bounty.